# How to create leadconvertion?

Tags: apex

Hi i am tring to save code for lead conversion these line getting error:

```
  public class leadconvertion{
   public String[] convertLeadRecords() {
   String[] result = new String[4];
   try {

      Lead[] leads = new Lead[2];
      Lead lead = new Lead();
      lead.setLastName('Mallard');
      lead.setFirstName('Jay');
      lead.setCompany('Wingo Ducks');
      lead.setPhone('(707) 555-0328');
      leads[0] = lead;
      lead = new Lead();
      lead.setLastName('Platypus');
      lead.setFirstName('Ogden');
      lead.setCompany('Denio Water Co.');
      lead.setPhone('(775) 555-1245');
      leads[1] = lead;
      SaveResult[] saveResults = connection.create(leads);


      LeadConvert[] leadsToConvert = new LeadConvert[saveResults.length];

      for (int i = 0; i < saveResults.length; ++i) {
         if (saveResults[i].isSuccess()) {
            System.out
                  .println("Created new Lead: " + saveResults[i].getId());
            leadsToConvert[i] = new LeadConvert();
            leadsToConvert[i].setConvertedStatus("Closed - Converted");
            leadsToConvert[i].setLeadId(saveResults[i].getId());
            result[0] = saveResults[i].getId();
         } else {
            System.out.println("\nError creating new Lead: "
                  + saveResults[i].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
         }
      }

      LeadConvertResult[] lcResults = connection.convertLead(leadsToConvert);
      for (integer j = 0; j < lcResults.length; ++j) {
         if (lcResults[j].isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println('Lead converted successfully!');
            System.out.println('Account ID: ' + lcResults[j].getAccountId());
            System.out.println('Contact ID: ' + lcResults[j].getContactId());
            System.out.println('Opportunity ID: '
                  + lcResults[j].getOpportunityId());
         } else {
            System.out.println('\nError converting new Lead: '
                  + lcResults[j].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
         }
      }
   } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
      ce.printStackTrace();
   }
   return result;
}
    }
```

error:

```
Compile Error: Invalid type: SaveResult,
Compile Error: Invalid type: LeadConvertResult
```

could you please any one help on this.

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: Now updated my full code

Comment: could you please tell me why these errors coming

Comment: any one tell me why i got error while i m save class "SaveResult[] saveResults = connection.create(leads);"

Answer (score 2):

The correct types are namespaced:

- `Database.SaveResult` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_saveresult))
- `Database.LeadConvertResult` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_database_leadconvertresult.htm#apex_class_database_leadconvertresult))